# Single TypeScript configuration + compilation command for all monorepo packages

Tags: typescript, build, monorepo

Let's say I have a monorepo with the following structure:

`├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── packages
    │── first
    │  ├── package.json
    │  └── src
    │      └── index.ts
    │── second
    │  ├── package.json
    │  └── src
    │      └── index.ts
    └── third
       ├── package.json
       └── src
           └── index.ts`

And I want to compile each package's TypeScript in such a way that the tree now becomes...

`├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── packages
    │── first
    │  ├── package.json
    │  ├── lib
    │  │   └── index.js
    │  └── src
    │      └── index.ts
    │── second
    │  ├── package.json
    │  ├── lib
    │  │   └── index.js
    │  └── src
    │      └── index.ts
    └── third
       ├── package.json
       ├── lib
       │   └── index.js
       └── src
           └── index.ts`

Can this be achieved without adding a new `tsconfig.json` (which would extend the root config) to each package? My hope is that I've missed something in the TS docs & that this is doable via changing up the root-level `tsconfig.json`. It'd be great to run a simple `tsc` from the root & see the desired result!

Thank you for taking a look at this question :) please let me know if you have questions or need clarification.